# How to integrate a clickable calendar in my app

Tags: android, android-view, android-calendar

I want to show a calendar in my app. I don't want to use it as a date picker, I want the user to be able to click on a date and select it. Then the click gets registered through a listener and I can save the clicked days.

I have looked on the internet but couldn't find a solution. Any ideas? Thanks.

This is what I have in mind.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`CalendarView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html):

```
mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO: make use of day selected
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but then can I show multiple selected days at once programmaticaly? Lets say that I pick the 1-2-3 of october, and save the dates in sharedPrefs, can I then show that they are all selected togheder (maybe with a different date color)?

Comment: @user11230 That is a more complex question. `CalendarView` does not natively support any form of multi-select, but you can always extend from it an try to add this functionality. Or you can look for another library that will handle multi-select; possibly [Android Times Square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) or [Material Calendar View](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview).

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to find a simplier solution as I never worked with custom views before and wouldn't know where to start. I'll see those libariries.